# any way to dynamically set this property value?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I've created a custom AuthorizeAttribute. A BaseUrl property value needs to be specified for it like this:

```
[CustomSecurityAuthorize(Roles=@"SuperUser,Admin", BaseUrl=@"http://my-server.com")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
}
```

BaseUrl is used to specify the environment for the underlying user-role lookup. For example, the value in the code example above could be:

- http://qa.my-server.com
- http://staging.my-server.com
- http://my-server.com

I'd like to make this value easily configurable (instead of hard-coded) for apps which implement it. For example, the code example above would require me to manually change the value for every instance in the app every time I pushed the app to a new enviornment.

Is there a clever way in which I could set the BaseUrl value dynamically via config file?  One interesting constraint is that the decorator is placed on top of the class as opposed to within it so not sure if the standard ConfigurationManager access will work in this scenario.

Comment: Attributes are embedded meta information and can't be changed once compiled.

Comment: consider using a configuration file instead and read it at runtime.

Comment: thanks daniel. sounds like I should require the user to configure an appsetting like:

< add key="CustomSecurityBaseUrl" value="http://my-server.com" />

I think I should be able to add validation code to the custom AuthorizeAttribute to throw an exception with a descriptive message if the expected appsetting has not been configured